# Alternative to for loop to loop through rows of an np.array

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, row

I have two numpy arrays. I would like to use the values inside each row of the array `p` as indices for the array `food` in the `consume` function. Unfortunately, it takes very long with the `for` loop when `p` get to the size of `2000` rows.

Would there be a faster alternative to the `for` loop in the `consume` function? I will appreciate any help to approach this issue.

```
import numpy as np
dt = 0.1
k = 2
p = np.array([[50, 50, 50],
              [ 0,  0,  0],
              [51, 51, 50],
              [52, 50, 51],
              [52, 51, 51],
              [50, 49, 49],
              [50, 49, 48],
              [51, 50, 50],
              [49, 49, 50],
              [53, 49, 51],
              [50, 51, 50],
              [51, 52, 51]])
food = np.ones((101, 101, 101))

def consume():
    for i in range(1, p.shape[0]):
         e = p[i - 1:i]
         food[e[0, 0], e[0, 1], e[0, 2]] -= dt * k

consume()
```

Comment: `p[i-1:i]` is more simply `p[i-1]`, with the appropriate index into `p` reduced to 1D

Answer (score 1):

Read [Indexing Multi-Dimensional Arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Basically if you want to access `food[x1, y1, z1]`, `food[x2, y2, z2]` ... `food[xn, yn, zn]` values from food, you can use `food[[x1, x2, .. , xn], [y1, y2, .., yn], [z1, z2, .., zn]]`

Use:

```
food[p[:, 0], p[:, 1], p[:, 2]] -= dt*k
```

Comment: Those should be `p[:-1, 0], p[:-1, 1], p[:-1, 2]` since the the range goes from 1 to shape. The max `i` is one less than the end of the array. Unless that's a mistake in the question.

Comment: @HenryEcker I am assuming it to be a mistake in the question. OP mentions ` would like to use the values inside each row of the array p as indexes`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop at all here. Fancy indexing will allow you to do exactly what you want by just transposing `p` and turning it into a `tuple`.

If you have no duplicates, just use the index as-is:

```
food = np.ones((101, 101, 101))
food[tuple(p[:-1].T)] -= dt * k
```

I am not sure why you were iterating in such a strange manner. A range is exclusive on the upper bound. To iterate over all the rows of `p`, you just need `for i in range(p.shape[0]):` or even just `for i in range(len(p)):`. You could even do `for e in p:`. If that is really what you wanted, you don't need to subset `p` in the above expression:

```
food[tuple(p.T)] -= dt * k
```

Furthermore, there is no need to index `e = p[i - 1:i]` when you can do `e = p[i - 1]` (or just `i`, or make it the loop variable. Then, instead of having a 2D index, you can assign to `food[tuple(e)] = ...`.

If there are duplicate indices in `p`, you can handle them using `np.subtract.at`:

```
np.subtract.at(food, tuple(p[:-1].T), dt * k)
```

This operation is unbuffered, so it will honor duplicate indices by subtracting them off twice. It works in-place.